# How to send values to from android to a html page in webview

Tags: android

I need to pass a value from java to the html in android.
i am having a list view, from which i am selecting a particular item,
the selected item should appear on the html page in a webview
is there any way to do it in android, kindly help me please,
i have searched many websites but all got in vain,

Thanks and Regards

rajesh

Answer (score 0):

The [`loadData (String data, String mimeType, String encoding)`](http://goo.gl/R4iaH) method of `WebView` allows you to send HTML source directly into the `WebView`. So, when your item is selected, generate the appropriate HTML from the item's data and then send it straight in.

Comment: Thanks for your quik reply Mr Borland the problem is i am using a single html file as a template for loading muliple items from the listview . The Title will differ for each items and the it has its own description for each item.The list holds nearly 100 items. so i am searching for a method which can use a single html file for viewing different datas. kindly send me any links for my reference